# Convertir variable a cadena en ensamblador

Tags: ensamblador, assembly

Quiero imprimir los numeros del 0 al 100 en **ensamblador**, soy nuevo en esto y mi lógica es la siguiente:

```
var1 db 0
var2 db 1

principio:
 
    mov cx, 50
    
    ciclo:    
        xor ax, ax
        
        add al, var1
        add al, var2
        mov var1, al
        
        mov dx, var1
        mov ah, 02h
        int 21h
        
        loop ciclo
```

Pero al  momento de mandar a imprimir me imprime los caracteres **ASCII**.
¿Cómo puedo convertir el resultado de la suma decimal en una cadena para mandar a imprimirla?